# $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^n)$ what am I doing wrong?

Tags: algebraic-topology, higher-homotopy-groups

I have come to contradiction trying to compute $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^n)$ (n > 1).
First of all we notice that the composition
$S^n \to S^n \vee S^n \to S^n$ is identity map (the first arrow is embedding to the first sphere and the second arrow maps the second sphere to basepoint).

Applying the functor we observe that the map $\phi: \pi_n(S^n \vee S^n) \to \pi_n(S^n )$ has a section (in particular is epimorphism). This means the following sequence:
$0 \to Ker(\phi) \to \pi_n(S^n \vee S^n) \to \pi_n(S^n ) \to 0 $ is exact and splits, i.e $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^n) = Ker(\phi) \oplus \pi_n(S^n )$.

Now the we need to compure the kernel but it is exactly those spheroids images of which lie in the second sphere, i.e. $\pi_n(S^n )$.
Finally, we have $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^n) = \pi_n(S^n ) \oplus \pi_n(S^n )$.

But! If I did the same for $S^n \vee S^1$ I would obtain $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^1) =\mathbb{Z}$. However, from exact sequence for bundles we obtain $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^1) = \pi_n(S^n \vee S^n ... \vee S^n)$. Well, what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "However, from exact sequence for bundles we obtain $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^1) = \pi_n(S^n \vee S^n ... \vee S^n)$."?

Comment: When you compute the kernel of $\phi$, while it is plausible to argue that it's the maps to the second sphere, but is that really a proof? When $n=1$ it's false...

Comment: As you say at the start of the post, you want to assume $n > 1$.  The higher ($k > 1$) homotopy groups $\pi_k(X)$ are isomorphic to those of the universal cover of $X$.  For $S^2 \vee S_1$, for instance, you can see that the universal cover has an infinitely generated second homotopy group since the universal cover is the real line with 2-spheres attached at each integer point.

Comment: @Dan Rust , I meant that groups $\pi_n(S^n \vee S^1)$ are the same as the groups of universal cover which is infinite number of spheres.

Comment: Your assumpti0on "...it is exactly those spheroids images of which lie in the second sphere" is incorrect. Basically because the pinch map $S^n\vee S^n\rightarrow S^n$ is not a fibration, you need to consider its *homotopy fibre*, rather than its strict fibre, when making arguments with homotopy exact sequences.

Answer (score 3):

> Now the we need to compure the kernel but it is exactly those spheroids images of which lie in the second sphere, i.e. $\pi_n(S^n )$.

This is wrong.  The kernel of $\phi$ is just the kernel of $\phi$: those maps $f:S^n\to S^n\vee S^n$ such that their composition with the map $S^n\vee S^n\to S^n$ is nullhomotopic.  This does not necessarily mean that the image of $f$ is contained in the second sphere, or even that $f$ is homotopic to a map whose image is contained in the second sphere (since the homotopy we have is only after composing with the map $S^n\vee S^n\to S^n$, not a homotopy of $f$ itself).  If you don't believe me, I challenge you to write down a detailed proof that the image of $f$ must be contained in the second sphere.

(This description of the kernel of $\phi$ happens to be correct in this particular example, but for much more subtle reasons that do not generalize to other examples like $S^1\vee S^n$.)

Comment: Could you explain how do I compute the kernel then?

Comment: I don't know any nice way to compute it directly.  I would instead first compute $\pi_n(S^n\vee S^n)$ using the Hurewicz theorem.

Comment: I am not allowed to use Hurewicz theorem, that's why I asked my question at the first place.

Comment: Well...I would reprove the Hurewicz theorem and then use that :).  Probably there is another way but nothing is coming to mind at the moment.